# Linq to SQL - Submit Changes not adding to database

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have this pretty simple method:

```
internal void Add(RecipeRecord recipeRecord)
{
    this.Database.GetTable<RecipeRecord>().InsertOnSubmit(recipeRecord);
    this.Database.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The entity I'm inserting is a valid entity. When I call SubmitChanges, nothing happens. No errors and no row added to the database. There is no transaction active. If I call GetChangeSet() on the context object, I see the single entity to add. After SubmitChanges(), the change set is empty.

Can anyone see what might be wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I think you may have to use context.attach I ran in to a similar issue and that got me going in the right direction.

Comment: You don't use Attach on an insert, only for detached updates.

Comment: DOh! my bad. Let me see if I can reproduce .InsertOnSubmit

Comment: Ok stupid question here, but are you getting an exception of any sort. I did not see a try catch in your posting so wondering.

Comment: I am not having any issues on this end with my SubmitChanges(). Did you make sure your connection strings are correct and you are looking in the right dtabase for your changes? It has been known to happen. In fact it has happened to me :)